# strophejs conflict with mootools

Tags: jquery, xmpp, mootools, conflict, strophe

I am trying to use strophe.js in Joomla! for xmpp chat client, but its giving me this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined strophe.js:3046
Strophe.Connection._onRequestStateChange strophe.js:3046
(anonymous function) mootools-core.js:88
(anonymous function) mootools-core.js:88
Strophe.Connection._processRequest strophe.js:2954
Strophe.Connection._throttledRequestHandler strophe.js:3022
Strophe.Connection.connect strophe.js:2399
conn.connect index.js:85
LoginPanel.Backbone.View.extend.connect converse.js:2761
LoginPanel.Backbone.View.extend.authenticate converse.js:2811
bound underscore.js:592
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle
```

Is there any way to solve this conflict? or is there any alternative of strophe.js?

Comment: Please add urs to stophe.js, some code that instantiates it and what it runs with (dom etc), un-minified. Otherwise, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Actually I have solved this error. Just replaced mootools with latest version. Should I delete this question?

Comment: sure, going to vote to close. if you think this will be encountered by others, add original version of mootools and the version you replaced it with in your own answer

Comment: Yes, please do answer the question so it can be useful for others or delete it. Please add version info and url to the answer, and I give it a + vote.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use strophe.js with mootools.js.
This was because of **conflicting bind function**.
Strophe and mootools, both were trying to override this core javascript function.
But this is the issue when you use older mootools version or new mootools with backward compatibility.
I was using mootools version 1.4.5(latest one) but backward compatible version in Joomla 2.5. So I just downloaded new mootools with the same version number but excluding compatibility for version 1.3 and 1.2. And now its working.

So I guess strophe is not working with **mootools** version **< 1.4** and **>= 1.4 with backward compatibility**.

If you want to use strophe with mootools you have to use newer version with no backward compatibility.